# First Version of db2 to include bigInt data type

Tags: db2, bigint

What is the first version of db2 to include the BigInt data type?

I thought it was version 8, but I'm looking for an official IBM source. I wasn't having much luck with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking about non-mainframe DB2. It goes back to at least [version 6](http://webdocs.caspur.it/ibm/udb-6.1/db2s0/varstrt.htm#Header_123).

I think version 5 was the first non-mainframe one so I'm not sure how far back you need to go?

Answer (score 2):

BIGINT was introduced with DB2 Universal Database Version 5.2, in September, 1998.

Here is a link to IBM's official [announcement letter](https://www-304.ibm.com/jct01003c/cgi-bin/common/ssi/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&htmlfid=897/ENUS298-344&appname=usn&language=enus).